# How to stop MediaPlayer when starting MediaPlayer other application?

Tags: android

I have two different application play music in the background. The first application is playing state. How to stop status playing of the first application when I open the second application and play music with MediaPlayer?

Comment: register through Broadcast it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kind of Mediaplayer (an similar things) should implement/use AudioFocus to take/release the exclusively of audio reproduction. AudioFocus manages "who is the current most important player". You will have an Event/Listener to receive a signal when some-other Player wants to be the "most important" (in this case the yours should stops). Please refer to the guide:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus